# What is a word for supplies sent by a country to aid another impoverished country?

Tags: single-word-requests

I forgot the word that describes items sent by a country to help people in suffering countries.

Example: Despite the risk of aiding another country, the US sent ____ to Syrian refugee camps.

Thanks,

Comment: I'll be honest -- what came to mind for me was _aid_.  On a more individual basis, you might send a _care package_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**relief** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/161917?rskey=mUM0Lh&result=2#eid)

> Alleviation of or deliverance from distress;  Assistance in time of
>   danger, need, or difficulty; aid, help, or support.

Answer (score 3):

**[Foreign aid](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/foreign-aid)** or more specifically [**humanitarian aid**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanitarian_aid).

> economic and other assistance given by one country to another

In this case, just [aid](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/aid) would work:

> Despite the risk of aiding another country, the US sent aid to Syrian
>   refugee camps.

Comment: I was trying to shy away from the word "aid" to avoid repetition. But I guess Foreign aid could work.

Comment: @NigelLeBlanc alternatively you could substitute "aiding" for something else? Maybe _Despite the risk of sending resources abroad, the US sent aid to Syrian refugee camps._

Comment: "Aid" can be given even to not so impoverished nations.

Comment: @NigelLeBlanc: There are probably dozens of words you could use instead of “aiding” — such as the obvious “helping” (you used “help” in your question), or “assisting”, “supporting”, “sustaining”, etc.